# How to open Teams meeting link in electron based app(or Chromium)

Tags: electron, microsoft-teams

I am trying to open Teams meeting link which is generate by Outlook Teams plugin(This link can be copied while you opening a Outlook meeting mail and is located at "Join Microsoft Teams Meeting"). But I can't open this link in any electron-based app:

1. Chromium
2. Electron official demo app: https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
   and I using loadURL() to do it.

It works well if I open this link in Chrome. So I guess it is the not supported by Microsoft. Do you have any solution? Thanks.

Comment: We have no idea what you are taking about.

Comment: My understanding of this query is, you are trying to integrate the meeting invite URL into any electron based app and trying to access it, is it the case?
if not what the exact scenario is and what error are you facing?
In case you are trying to open the meeting URL from electron based app then it will redirect you to Chrome and in turn Chrome browser will ask you to open teams app and you should be able to join the meeting.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT, Yes, that is what exactly I am doing, but I don't wan't to redirect to Chrome or open Teams app. I want to join meeting in my electron app. Another tried is that I studied Chromium is also electron based app, so I pasted meeting invite URL to Chromium and it still not work.

Comment: This is not supported. URL will redirect you to chrome and open team from there.